# convert a string or byte to a hex decimal in c#

Tags: c#, hex, byte, listener, converters

I have a sensor that gets the request and gives me its value the request should be hex format in c# as you can see in the picture :

[image]

My request that i enter in the `textbox` is like this :`"000100020005030190000212BD"`

but as you can see the hex `checkbox` is checked and it converts my request to `hex` how can i do that ?
Here is my code that send the request "

```
 var listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 3000);
listener.Start();

using (var client = listener.AcceptTcpClient())
using (var stream = client.GetStream())
{

    // build a request to send to sensor
    var request = new byte[2048];

    stream.Write(request, 0, request.Length);
    // read a response from sensor;
    // note, that respose colud be broken into several parts;
    // you should determine, when reading is complete, according to the protocol for the sensor
    while (true)
    {                    
        // stream.Read calls here
    }
}
```

datasheet :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To convert a string to Hexadecimal, you can use

```
public string function HexConvert(string InputText)
{
    StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    char[] lettercollection = InputText.ToCharArray();
    foreach (char letter in lettercollection)
    {
        int integerValue = Convert.ToInt32(letter); //convert to integer
        string hexCode = String.Format("{0:X}", integerValue); //hex generation
        sb.append(hexCode); 
    }
    return sb.ToString(); //your output
}
```